# Why does Zuko cry at the top of the mountain in book 2 episode 9 ("Bitter Work")?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender

Possible reasons I can think of -

1. He yells at the storm that he can take whatever it throws at him and that it (the storm, and in general, the universe) has "never held back before". This implies his life of hardship and struggle and his constant failures (up until that point) and this realization/admittance hits him hard.
2. He begs for a lightning to strike him, in order for a desperate chance to prove himself as a master at lightning redirection, but nothing happens and he takes this as "another failure" and a lost chance at even the feeblest attempt at becoming better.

Does anyone know of any better reason? Has this already been answered somewhere?

Comment: https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Bitter_Work - *Standing alone at the top of a mountain, Zuko yells defiantly into the raging thunderstorm as lightning crackles overhead. He challenges the storm to strike him, yelling that he can take whatever it throws at him and that it has "never held back before". The storm does not oblige, however, and Zuko falls to his knees in tears, crying out in anguish.*

Comment: @Valorum - I read that description and it just says that Zuko cries out in anguish, but why though? Why is he so agitated and frustrated at something he's trying for the very first time? On top of which, he doesn't even get a chance to try it (since no lightning hit him).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By this point in the story, Zuko's life has been pretty much nothing but one failure after another.  As Ozai said, Azula was born lucky, Zuko was lucky to be born.  He failed when he challenged the general to agni kai, he failed when he refused to fight his father, he failed to find the Avatar for approximately a year, he failed to capture the Avatar about a dozen times by this point.  In the episode in question, Zuko has just failed to bend lightning, a technique he believes will be essential if he ever fights Azula again.  This is just the last straw; his self-esteem is crushed, his whole life has been one example after the next that he can't do anything right.  He wants the storm to hit him with lightning so he can redirect it and prove to himself that he's not worthless.  And even this is a failure, he can't even get hit by lightning.

It's even worse though, because not only is he embarrassed that he can't beat Azula, he stands to lose his only chance at redemption and a ticket home.  If Zuko captures the Avatar, Azula can just defeat Zuko, steal the Avatar from him, and take all the credit.  So not only is his self-worth tenuous at best, there are real material consequences for his failures.

Comment: I thought he hunted the Avatar for about three years

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken, idk.